# JAX-RS bean validation with RestEasy and JBoss 7.1 doesn't work

Tags: web-services, validation, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

I would like to enable validation parameters in `JAX-RS` web service. I'm using `JavaEE 6`, `RestEasy 3.0.6.Final` and `JBoss 7.1 Final` as Application Server.

I wrote this simple WS:

```
@Path("/accounts")
public interface MyWS {

    @PUT
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ValidateRequest
    public Response createUser(@Valid User request);

}

public class MyWsImpl implements MyWS {

    private static Logger LOG =  LogManager.getLogger(MyWsImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Response createUser(User request) {

    LOG.info("doing");
    return Response.status(200).build();

    }

}

public class User {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=50)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String surname;

...
}
```

Doing the request, server logs are:

```
17:21:05,324 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) 17:21:05.324 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-2] DEBUG [RS-WS-Invoke] - PUT (/accounts) - 127.0.0.1

17:21:05,355 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) annotation[0]: @javax.ws.rs.Path(value=/accounts)

17:21:05,373 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) 17:21:05.373 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-2] INFO  it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.paas.services.smsaas.MyWsImpl - doing

17:21:05,374 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) declaring class: interface it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.paas.services.smsaas.MyWS

17:21:05,374 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) annotation[0]: @javax.ws.rs.Path(value=/accounts)

17:21:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) 17:21:05.379 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-2] DEBUG [RS-WS-Invoke-Response] - PUT (/accounts) - 127.0.0.1 - RESPONSE[Status:400, Time:55ms]
```

but I expect that a `ValidationException` raise and that the code will be not executed.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the ValidationInterceptor ?

```
<interceptors>
    <class>org.jboss.seam.rest.validation.ValidationInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

([tutorial link](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/rest/latest/reference/en-US/html/rest.validation.html))

Comment: I'm using annotations for configuration my application. How can I enable the interceptor as you suggest? I have followed this documentation https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e2459